# Should we accept geographical/archaeological questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I think the title is not good enough to describe the category but is close enough. Recently we got two questions,

- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2911/
- [Location of Hindu Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2910/)
- [Where are the original versions of the Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2628/) (Bit old)

So should we accept such questions? According to me, they are somewhat on topic but not important for the site. It doesn't contribute much in terms of knowledge. The questions are somewhat geographical, contributing their current location is not helping much.

Also, expect few questions ahead,

- Where is lord Krishnas Sudarshan Chakra
- Where is lord Hanumans Gada

And so on, so should we mark them as off-topic for the site or we should be accepting? If we should accept the questions then why?

Comment: I think questions about where ancient manuscripts are located are fine.  The two questions about "original manuscripts" of the Vedas are problematic only because they're based on the incorrect assumption that there are such things as original manuscripts of the Vedas, when the Vedas were passed down via oral tradition originally.  (And those two questions seem like duplicates.)

Comment: As far as questions about the location of the Sudarshana Chakra and the like, that should absolutely be on topic, because those sorts of questions are addressed in Hindu scripture.  (By the way, as far as I know, there are no scriptures that say that Hanuman ever had a Gada; that may just be something artists have added.)

Comment: If we look in other perspective like there might be a story in scriptures about the whereabouts of a book or aretefact which makes the question valid.

Comment: these questions do make sense to me, there are a lot of places in India having religious importance because of what the scriptures say..i personally feel they do provide knowledge abut Hinduism in some way or the other

Comment: Geographical questions are on topic. Questions that are based off false assumptions should be edited, and the selected/highest voted answer should also have explain why the assumption is incorrect (as in the case of 'original' Vedic manuscripts).

Comment: Difficult to take a general decision. Maybe we should define a close vote reason for such questions in general and put them on hold. Then discuss in chat with knowledgeable users and open if they could be answered.